# Parsing multiply-nested Ansible variables

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have an Ansible template for a complex environment which has a variable:

`{{ a }}`

which has a value defined in `defaults/main.yml`. This is overridden by a variable, `{{ b }}`, in a `group_vars` file. However, this is made up of other variables, `{{ c }}` and `{{ d }}` earlier on in the group_vars file.

This recursion continues to happen a few layers deeper.

Is there a way of getting Ansible to parse these variables so you can clearly see what the value is?

Answer (score 0):

I think the debug module would be helpful here to print out the value of the value during a playbook run. If you're wanting to do it before execution, I'm not aware of any way to do that.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/debug_module.html